# Agora SDK Setup

Tags: video, webrtc, agora.io

I’m trying to using the Agora SDK (www.agora.io) to add a 1:1 video call into my iOS app. I’m trying to follow your SDK guide, but could use some help. How do I set up the call?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of steps to set up a call. The flowchart below walks you through it.

[Agora Call Setup Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjSQA.jpg)

You can also refer to sections of our AgoraDemo app, which we have included the source code.
 
First, you have to create the AgoraRTCEngine:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AgoraRtcEngineKit *agoraKit;
```

Next, you have to initialize it with your vendor key (note in our demo app, we use a UITextInput for vendorKey from the previous storyboard page):

```
self.agoraKit = [AgoraRtcEngineKit sharedEngineWithVendorKey:self.vendorKey delegate:self];
```

Next, enableVideo:

```
[self.agoraKit enableVideo];
```

You are then ready to joinChannel to talk to other participants:

```
[self.agoraKit joinChannelByKey:nil channelName:self.channel info:nil uid:0 joinSuccess:^(NSString *channel, NSUInteger uid, NSInteger elapsed) {
```

If you want to display your local video, first bind the AgoraRTCVideoCanvas to the view:

```
AgoraRtcVideoCanvas *videoCanvas = [[AgoraRtcVideoCanvas alloc] init];
videoCanvas.uid = unsignedIntegerValue; // Use your own User ID (UID)
videoCanvas.view = self.videoMainView;
videoCanvas.renderMode = AgoraRtc_Render_Hidden;
```

Then call setupLocalVideo to specify you want your local video in that view:

```
[self.agoraKit setupLocalVideo:videoCanvas];
```

When a 2nd participant joins the same channel, the delegate method didJoinedofUID will be called:

```
- (void)rtcEngine:(AgoraRtcEngineKit *)engine didJoinedOfUid:(NSUInteger)uid elapsed:(NSInteger)elapsed
{
    // (Do something) Your code
}
```

Decide which view you want to bind that remote participant’s video to:

```
AgoraRtcVideoCanvas *videoCanvas = [[AgoraRtcVideoCanvas alloc] init];
videoCanvas.uid = unsignedIntegerValue; // Use your own User ID (UID)
videoCanvas.view = self.videoMainView;
videoCanvas.renderMode = AgoraRtc_Render_Hidden;
```

Then call  setupRemoteVideo to specify you want that participant’s remote video in that view:

```
[self.agoraKit setupRemoteVideo:videoCanvas];
```

If participants leave the channel, the delegate method  didOfflineOfUid will be called:

```
- (void)rtcEngine:(AgoraRtcEngineKit *)engine didOfflineOfUid:(NSUInteger)uid reason:(AgoraRtcUserOfflineReason)reason
{
      // (Do something) Your code
}
```

At the end of the call, call leaveChannel:

```
[self.agoraKit leaveChannel:nil];
```

Comment: can you reply answer in swift?

Comment: Please have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74223998/agorartcexception-agorartcerror-ws-abort-type-ping